# Refactor this function to use "return" consistently

Tags: node.js, callback, eslint

I have a JS function for which I am getting eslint error as Refactor this function to use "return" consistently. But looks like I am always returning. Can any one suggest how I can resolve this?

```
function filterBooks(books, context, purpose, callback) {
    if (!context && !purpose) {
        logger.warn("context and purpose not found so ingnoring the filtering on context and purpose");
        return callback(null, books);
    } else {
        if (purpose) {
            filterBooksByPurpose(books, purpose);
        }
        if (context) {
                filterBooksByContext(books, context,function(err,books){
                if(err){
                    return callback(err, null);
                }else{
                    books = removebooksEmptyPages(books);
                    return callback(null, books);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the consumer of `filterBooks` ever use the return value? (it doesn't look like it, since a callback is passed? if not, just remove all the `return`s)

Comment: @certainPerformance it worked for me. Thanks

Comment: @CertainPerformance Can you help me understand in case of callbacks, when to return and when not to.

Comment: If the function is passed a callback, and the callback is always invoked at the end, then the function probably shouldn't return anything - any data that needs to be communicated back can be sent via the callback.

Comment: It seems that you use callbacks where they aren't suitable. filterBooksByContext isn't shown. Is it synchronous too? Don't use callbacks then.

Answer (score 1):

the `else` block does not have any return value but the `if` block does, which is why the linter complains. Commented in the code block below

```
function filterBooks(books, context, purpose, callback) {
    if (!context && !purpose) {
        logger.warn("context and purpose not found so ingnoring the filtering on context and purpose");
        return callback(null, books);
    } else {
        // *********** no return value in this block
        if (purpose) {
            filterBooksByPurpose(books, purpose);
        }
        if (context) {
                // there is no return here as well, the callback function has return value but not for filterBooks
                filterBooksByContext(books, context,function(err,books){
                if(err){
                    return callback(err, null);
                }else{
                    books = removebooksEmptyPages(books);
                    return callback(null, books);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This linter rule addresses a problem with inconsistency in function returns, it usually indicates either a mistake or code smell.

If `filterBooks` is synchronous, it should either consistently return a result or provide side effects (modify `books`) with no return. If `filterBooks` is asynchronous, it can't return a result synchronously.

`callback` is Node-style error-first callback. They are commonly used in asynchronous code, and asynchronous function can't return a value from asychronously called callback.

`filterBooks` appears to be synchronous, so the use of callbacks is unjustified.

If it's currently used as:

```
filterBooks(..., (err, result) => {
  if (err)
    console.error(err);
  else
    console.log(result);
});
```

It can be refactored to be used like:

```
try {
    const result = filterBooks(...);
    console.log(result);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

So can other functions in use like `filterBooksByContext`.